# Common word in vector with how many times word occurred C++

Tags: c++

Hey everyone I am trying to figure out how to find the common word in a vector with how many times it occurred. My professor wants us to go through the vector with two for loops, but I am stuck because the loop will re-count already counted words and gives crazy outputs. I am a new programmer in my first programming class and finding all this very difficult. This is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    int max_count {1};
    vector<string> input{};

    while (cin >> s)
    {
        input.push_back(s);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
    {

        for (int k = i + 1; k < input.size(); ++k)
        { 
            if (input[i] == input[k])
            {
                s = input[k];
                ++max_count;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << s << " occurs " << max_count << " times " << endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate it if you would provide some example of pairs of input and desired output.

Comment: You should add `#include <string>` because you seems using `std::string`.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a std::map<string, int>?  I find those very useful for making histograms of word-counts, etc.

Comment: I do not see why you need to use 2 for loops if you can achieve the goal with one

Answer (score 0):

simple solution using no additional data structures:

```
int prevRel = -1;
std::string last = "";

for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
{
    int relcount = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < input.size(); ++k)
    { 
        if (input[i] == input[k])
            relcount++;
    }
    if(relcount > prevRel) {
        prevRel = relcount;
        last = input[i]
    }
}
```

solution is now in `last` with an absolute number of `prevRel` occurences

Comment: This is not scaleable.  Time taken is the square of the number of input words.  Increase word count by ten times, this code will take 100 times longer.

Comment: i agree with you, but `first programming class` should favor simplicity over efficiency imho

Answer (score 0):

This uses a map, so that one pass through the word list is required and a binary search is used to find the possibly matching word - meaning that it becomes more efficient the more words are input.  If you input ten time more words, this will run LESS than ten times more slowly.

Running [here](http://ideone.com/7TdMI1)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {

     vector<string> input 
        { "the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped",
            "over", "the", "the", "lazy", "dog" };

    map< string, int > histogram;
    string most_common_word = input[0];
    int max_count = 1;

    // loop over words
    for( auto& word : input)
    {
        // attempt to insert new word into histogram
        auto p = histogram.insert( pair< string, int >( word, 1 ) );

        if( ! p.second )
        {
            // word is not new, so increment count
            p.first->second++;

            // check for most common so far
            if( p.first->second > max_count )
            {
                // remember most common so far
                most_common_word = word;
                max_count = p.first->second;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "'" << most_common_word << "' occurs " << max_count << " times " << endl;    

    return 0;
}
```